# Waste Foundry Sand as an aggregate for concrete mixes. I have a question regarding grain diameter and it's possible applications

Tags: concrete, industrial-engineering, construction-management

I'm working on a project with a company that uses sand casts during moulding processes and they provided us with samples of the sand they use before it's involved in the procedure and afterwards (Waste foundry sand). I'm wondering if there's specific parameters regarding grain size for using WFS as an aggregate for concrete mixes, my samples led me to believe that most of the WFS this company produces is about 1/2 mm to 1 mm in diameter. A brief literature review has offered no conclusive results and little information regarding specific gran diameter in WFS. Is this byproduct suitable for concrete mixing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What grain size is used in concrete mixes? What particular concrete mix are you considering? What purpose is your concrete for?

Comment: We've considered _Portland Pozzolana_ in our general review of the matter but any solution we come up with would preferably be appliable to any concrete mix and be suitable for most general applications. I'm unsure as to the diameter of fine aggregates in regular concrete mixes and that is partly why I asked the qustion in the first place.